# Tool tip for hidden text works only in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I have the following css code that uses ellipsis to hide data that overflows.

```
.foo {
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

here is my html:

```
  <div class="foo">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span>
  </div>
```

Here is my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/KsrDh/

When I hover over it in safari, it shows a tooltip for it by default.

But it doesn't do that for other browsers. Is there I can make it applicable on all the browsers?

Comment: In Safari 5.1.8, I see nothing of what you're talking about

Comment: he forget to say, that he use any kind of js(-framework) to enable the "tool-tip-effect" the css and html is correct ...

Comment: You did not set `title`, a tooltip should not appear.

Comment: @Dom They said "it doesn't do that for other browsers" which leads me to believe it's something special happening in Safari, not the `title` attribute (which will work on "all" browsers). But it doesn't matter because I don't even see something happening specifically in Safari

Comment: to prove I am not lying, I have attached the js fiddle screenshot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Safari is the only browser that assumes you want it displayed when someone mouses over it. If that is the desired effect, then add the content in the title. Then all browsers should see it.

```
<div class="foo">
 <span title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
 </span>
</div>

.foo {
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSz3D/